# Microsoft Teams "Files" tab missing on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, microsoft

Unfortunately, we are unable to visit the user in person and they are not very technically able, so apologies in advance for the lack of information available.

Model: ?
iOS Version: ?

We have tried removing the app and reinstalling it.
We have also tried removing the app via "offload App" to remove any cache.

User has access to the rest of the functionality of the Teams app, however, there is no "Files" option in any of the groups or chats they have access to.

The Files option shows fine on the desktop, and they can access the files, so we know it's not an access rights issue.

Any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an iOS user, but I believe it's the same on a iOS device as it is on Android devices.

More tab in Bottom App Bar
[image: More in bottom bar]
Files from the Popup menu.

[image: Files tab]